# how do you Apply math multiply a number to a decimal point python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

i want apply lambda to do multiplication which is condition type data float value like this

0.412

0.0036

0.0467

0.000678

0.00000342

expected output

0.41

0.36

0.47

0.68

0.34

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html).

Try this :

```
df["col"] = df["col"].replace("\.0*", ".", regex=True).astype(float).round(2)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   col
0 0.41
1 0.36
2 0.47
3 0.68
4 0.34
```

Comment: not work for me, there still some data 0.07 not all converted become 0.7 only one decimal

Comment: And why you need `0.0467` to be `0.46` ? I tested `0.07` and I got `0.70`, so what's the problem ?

Comment: that sample from many data on dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
lambda_func = lambda x: re.sub(r'(\.0*)', r'.', str(x))
```

Comment: yes it worked, but there one column i have trouble after check it manually because there data without number but 0.00000 after implement 
df1["instrumentalness"] = df1["instrumentalness"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\.0*)', r'.', str(x)))
output 0. how to make value 0.00000 just 0 only

Comment: As there is no number after decimal, other than 0's, It can't display anything. If you have any specific output for such case write an if else clause in the lambda to print your desired output.

Comment: df1["instrumentalness"] = df1["instrumentalness"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\.0*)', r'.', '0') if x==0.000000 else re.sub(r'(\.00*)', r'.', str(x)))

Comment: im use that function but some get output like this 4.67e-05 value before 0.000047 and 3.22e-06 value before 0.000003 if im convert that string become float output is 0.000000 for 3.22e-06 & this 4.67e-05

Comment: @Rivaldy, [ \.0* == \.00* ]. ' * ' is added to consider 0 or more occurrences. Consider how many decimals are allowed, if count is greater than allowed then print 0.

Comment: can u write full code example